# How to say my friend with a name

Tags: names

For example, "my friend Tomoko"
Is it correct to say "友達の朋子?"
As in: 昨日、友達の朋子ちゃんと２人で買物に行きました。

Also, how would you say "my friend is called Tomoko"?

Comment: 朋子という友達 is my friend called Tomoko.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "友達の朋子" is perfectly fine and means "my friend Tomoko" like you thought.

If you want to say "my friend is called Tomoko"; I think that the simplest is "友達の名前は朋子です".

Answer (score 1):

When people introduce their family they often say something like this...

> 息子のタケシです
>
> 妻のアイコです

So, I would probably say something like...

> 友達の朋子です